# Android Keystore Type which one should I choose?

Tags: android, security, keystore

I want to store secure data in a keystore.
Therefore I use

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
```

But Android seems to not know "JCEKS".

```
04-18 10:52:17.236: WARN/System.err(474): java.security.KeyStoreException: KeyStore JCEKS implementation not found
```

Trying JKS gives the same error. 
What algorithm is good to use it on android?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android seems to be using bouncycastle provider. This is the default provider that, the api returns. To be sure which one is available as default on the device use `KeyStore.getDefaultType()`.

In my case this returned 'BKS'. Also there seems to be an exception when there is a '.' character in the keystore file path.

when I stored the store to a folder with the name of my package (as recommended in the Android documentation), it resulted in an exception.

you may like to check [this](http://harisankar-krishnaswamy.blogspot.com/2011/08/beginning-java-security-on-android.html) also.

Answer (score 4):

Did you load the keystore before you tried to access it?  Did the error message happen right at the getInstance instruction?

Some googling has said that "PKCS12" worked for a few people, give that a go.

Answer (score 3):

Use it's `KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");`

Create keystore with tool "KeyTools Explorer" !

Answer (score 2):

You need bouncy castle key store (BKS).
Take a look [here](http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
```

Remember to call `KeyStore.load(KeyStore.LoadStoreParameter param)` before calling `KeyStore.getEntry (String alias, KeyStore.ProtectionParameter param)`, i.e.

```
keyStore.load(null);
KeyStore.Entry keyStoreEntry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

see https://github.com/nelenkov/ecdh-kx/blob/master/src/org/nick/ecdhkx/Crypto.java

```
static public void listAlgorithms( String algFilter ){
    java.security.Provider[] providers = java.security.Security.getProviders();
    for ( java.security.Provider p : providers ){
        String providerStr = String.format( "%s/%s/%f\n", p.getName(), p.getInfo(),
                                            p.getVersion() );
        mLog.debug( providerStr );
        Set< Service > services = p.getServices();
        List< String > algs = new ArrayList<>();
        for ( Service s : services ){
            boolean match = true;
            if ( algFilter != null ){
                match = s.getAlgorithm().toLowerCase().contains( algFilter.toLowerCase() );
            }

            if ( match ){
                String algStr = String.format( "\t%s/%s/%s", s.getType(),
                                               s.getAlgorithm(), s.getClassName() );
                algs.add( algStr );
            }
        }

        Collections.sort( algs );
        for ( String alg : algs ) mLog.debug( "\t" + alg );
        mLog.debug( "" );
    }
}//listAlgorithms
```